# Mark of the Web and playing sounds in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have some local html files saved on my computer that contain javascript. I am using the mark of the web to make them run in Internet Explorer without getting a security warning every time I open them.
However, I have some MP3 sounds that play when the page is loaded etc and they are not playing after I've inserted the Mark of the Web. 
They played before I inserted the mark of the web and had to click on the security warning to run the webpage in IE. They play in firefox.

How can I get the sounds to play in IE when the mark of the web is inserted? Is there a hack or work around for this?

Thanks